# Strongloop loopback data control access based on ID, not user roles/acl

Tags: authentication, loopbackjs, strongloop, persistent-data

I'm looking for a clean and easy way to integrate loopback user authentication with my DB (mysql persistenModels).

I cannot change the database design since is already designed and contains data, furthermore, the people that are in charge don't want to change it even they know that it could be better.

Sorry for the drawing quality/errors but synthesizes the current structure on the database:

[image: user to tools relations]

I would like to validate the strongloop User model with the User table on DB, then somehow store on the session/cookie/memory model the collection of table_id's that he owns, since many users can access to same table object.

Is not just a ACL to hide endpoints or give permissions to update/remove, because the DB is read only. The best approach that I have found is this one: [Loopback - Implementing custom authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698115/loopback-implementing-custom-authentication/32703824#32703824)

But it doesn't solve the issue about if the Tools endpoint is published, anyone who knows the tool_id could access the data since User/Tables/Tools are PersistenModels that get the data from the database.

Currently I have all the endpoints implemented of Tables,Tools and others sub levels (Tools Parts,etc) with model relations with foreignkeys,keyThroughs... without problems (doesn't take into account the user permissions)

I have almost no experience with strongloop because I have been using it since 3 days ago , but I have good background with node.js and angular.js

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Look into the Role and RoleMapping models to help with this. You can restrict authenticated users to the database entities that they own using the $owner ACL. The actual implementation isn't super trivial but that might get you started with a more robust solution. You could also just add a beforeRemote hook to validate that a User has ownership before sending the results back.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I was thinking about this yesteday, But I was trying to implement with access hook that didn't worked.

I will try to map $owner to a list of Table id's and check every time that beforeRemote is called.

With your hint I'm thinking what is best, map owner acl to a list of table_id's or map Table object owner to a list of user_id's, since my public endpoint is Table, Tools and others that is Project that uses both as FK.